# Как прочитать из бинарного файла данные разных типов?

Tags: файлы, c++

Как обеспечить чтение из бинарного файла данных разных типов (в основном, `int`, `long`, `char[]`)? Известно смещение от начала и длина. 
Можно ли реализовать это с помощью функций `fseek`, `fscanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscanf немного не про то. Посмотрите в сторону [fread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246410%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но если я правильно понимаю, на выходе fread получается большая строка и придется её потом обрабатывать. Нет ли вариантов проще?

Comment: Виноват. Там ведь используется void * buf. Можно любое значение использовать. Вроде бы получилось что хотел. Благодарю :)

Answer (score 3):

fseek, fscanf скорее относится к C. Если нужно на C++, то могу посоветовать [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/)
и [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/). Как по мне, так там больше возможностей